# Creating COM serial port between external device (Joule/Arduino/etc.) and PC over Bluetooth w/ linux sdptool & rfcomm (OR another method)

Tags: communication, wireless, bluetooth, arduino, intel-edison

**This article is not device specific, but rather is focused on using sdptool and rfcomm to setup a serial com port connection over bluetooth. If you have another method instead of these two Linux modules that is welcomed as well! My specific example uses the Intel Joule, but alternative devices can still use sdptool and rfcomm. Please feel free to explain for an alternative device that you have experience with, it may help me resolve a similar issue using Joule.**

**Introduction:**
I am currently trying to create a COM port connection between my PC and the Intel Joule platform. I have been able to do it with a cord but I would like to control it over Bluetooth. I've already paired the device with my computer and am currently following this tutorial:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/721513

**Background for personal IoT system:**
I need to be able to create this serial connection over the Bluetooth port so that I can wirelessly collect data and store it to my local SQL. It would have to allow machines communicating as I want the data collection process to run completely autonomously. And I want an AI either on the joule or running through my client to use this data then run specific commands on the joule wirelessly through a serial Bluetooth connection. This type of serial connection through  Linux base using *sdptool* is used in many devices such as the Arduino and the Joule. Even if you do not have experience with the joule but do have experience setting up a COM serial connection over Bluetooth, it will likely be very helpful for me to understand how to establish the serial connection over Bluetooth. If you have managed to acquire the connection with an alternative device lease share the information, it could allow me to use that same train of thought on the Joule.

**Current Linux porting process and progress:**

I am able to add a serial port with:

```
sdptool add SP
```

But when I run rfcomm to watch to port using:

```
rfcomm watch hci0 1 getty rfcomm0 115200 vt100 -a root
```

I receive this:

```
RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
RFCOMM socket layer initialized
RFCOMM ver 1.11
Waiting for connection on channel 1
```

From there I return to my PC's Bluetooth settings and traverse to COM Ports (none show up). SO I click Add... and I've tried both Incoming and Outgoing connection (choosing the paired joule device). The result is this error:

The device you selected does not have a serial port service running

... but I mean in the device it's saying

> "waiting for connection on channel 1"

Comment: I was literally just told it wasn't acceptable as a stack overflow question. What do you think the intel joule is used for? It's an IoT platform. Please instead of preventing me from receiving help allow the question to stand. I require my Joule device to be remote written through a Bluetooth serial port as I can't pull it out of my IoT system every time. I really don't understand the reason for this block. I'm pulling out my hair moving from help site to help site just for people to say, "It's not relevant". I was told to come here and now I receive nothing once again. :(

Comment: Please give me an explanation or at very minimum a redirection to the correct help site. As far as I'm concerned this is exactly the site to help me out!

Comment: I should have put IoT in the title, maybe then it would be "relevant". Sorry, I'm just frustrated. I understand you are here to help facilitate the site and I appreciate that.

Comment: Sam, I am sorry that  I can't help you. This seems like an acecptable question to me, but you might try asking on https://communities.intel.com/community/tech/intel-joule/

Comment: Internet of Things SE-site is not about all aspects of embedded systems communications, like that of pc between microcontroller unless the connection is used for communicating between machines. Is that your case? Are the machines communicating independently or just when you ask to update sth?

Comment: Well that's the thing, I need to be able to create this serial connection over the Bluetooth port so that I can wirelessly collect data and store it to my local SQL. So yes it would be machines communicating as I want the data collection process to run completely autonomously. And I want an AI either on the joule or running through my client to use this data then run specific commands on the joule wirelessly through a serial Bluetooth connection. This knowledge isn't important to solve the question so I redacted it. But now that all this has come up I'll think twice about brevity.

Comment: Also learning this connection would prove helpful if I need new modules to be added to my project that can't be accessed directly.

Comment: Sorry if I am coming off a bit angry. I have the upmost respect for people who work/contribute to help sites like this. It isn't easy to deal with people with problems, especially when we are all engineers. Please caution me if I overstep my bounds.

Comment: @SamH. Sorry for the confusion, and welcome to the site.  I would definitely encourage you to include the data you've posted in comments in the question.  To me, the question looked like a generic embedded systems question, which aren't on topic here.  If you can edit your question to show how it directly relates to the IoT, it will be a much better fit for the site.

Comment: The scope of this question is either setting up a bluetooth channel from a device to your PC, (which is my guess) or in sending serial data from the endpoint to it's bluetooth channel. Either way, I think it's quite specific to the device. So whilst it _could_ be on-topic here, I the manufacturer forums are more likely to be effective. EE.SE would be the other possibility, but i don't think there is enough information here to get a generic diagnosis.

Comment: Very good point, I made the question less device specific but rather pertaining to creating a COM serial port connection over Bluetooth from a PC to an external device. This question shouldn't be specific to the Joule as the sdptool is used to develop the serial connection in many devices. This article is no longer about the Joule and no solely about the serial port connection.

Comment: Thank you for all of the support sob, Mawg, mico, anonymous2, Sean_Houlihane, I apologize for my novice resolve and will try and be more specific in the future. I appreciate all the work and consideration that you have all brought. Sorry for making this question messier than it had to be! Thanks again guys!

Comment: @sob If nobody answers in two weeks you can close it. I understand the goal of the site it to keep questions answered out of all questions high.

Comment: This question won't get answer here, needs so much hardware specific information.

Comment: @sob can you clean up these comments so that posting specific comments can be seen? I would like to see an answer or commentary on this question as I have something similar.

Comment: Here is an example of using python to build a server script and a client script using the rfcomm interface. https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x232.html  here is a pdf of a slide package about the rfcomm protocol http://hccc.ee.ccu.edu.tw/courses/bt/vg/rfcomm.pdf and this is a list of stackoverflow questions concerning rfcomm, some of which have answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rfcomm and see this Raspberry Pi forum discussion https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=125922

Comment: This might be an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028899/forward-bluetooth-socket-to-serial-port the solution uses a mix of bluez, sdptool, rfcomm and socat.